# TypeError: _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[7], "(...)ssets-registry/path-support.js") is not a function (it is Object)

Tags: react-native, image, require

I'm upgrading react-native from 0.62.2 to 0.72.0
when I upgraded Android Gradle Plugin Version, JDK Version, React-Native Version well.
Then
yarn start.

I got an error, here is error stack:

```
TypeError: _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[7], "(...)ssets-registry/path-support.js") is not a function (it is Object)

This error is located at:
    in BaseImage (created by ImageBackground)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by ImageBackground)
    .....
```

I tried to change all related configs.
I guess it's ImageComponent Render Error.